# C embedded convert float to int

Tags: c, arduino, embedded

Hello I am trying get to work a simple 5hz led via interrupt on an arduino. I want to calculate how many Timer overflows have to occure before I have to toggle my leds. However I cant compute the value properly for some reason I dont understand.
Here is my code:

```
#define OF_FREQUENCY F_CPU / 256.0
#define SECONDS_PER_OF 1 / OF_FREQUENCY
#define F_LEDS 5 
#define LED_CYCLE_TIME (1 / F_LEDS) / 2
#define OVERFLOWS_PER_CYCLE (unsigned int)(LED_CYCLE_TIME / SECONDS_PER_OF)
```

OVERFLOW_PER_CYCLE evaluates to 0 always but it should be 6250 as my F_CPU is 16E6.
I want to have an unsigned int at the end.

Comment: How is this question related to the title "_convert float to int_"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LED_CYCLE_TIME` is zero because you don't use floating point division (`(1 / F_LEDS) / 2` is `(1 / 5) / 2`, but `1 / 5 == 0`, so it's `0`).

Just use doubles: `#define LED_CYCLE_TIME (0.5 / F_LEDS)`

And you also need some extra brackets around your defines, since currently `OVERFLOWS_PER_CYCLE` is defined as `(unsigned int)((1 / F_LEDS) / 2 / 1 / F_CPU / 256.0)`, which does the division left-to-right instead of in the correct order.

So your corrected code:

```c
#define OF_FREQUENCY (F_CPU / 256.0)
#define SECONDS_PER_OF (1 / OF_FREQUENCY)
#define F_LEDS 5
#define LED_CYCLE_TIME (0.5 / F_LEDS)
#define OVERFLOWS_PER_CYCLE (unsigned int)(LED_CYCLE_TIME / SECONDS_PER_OF)
```

Comment: you are right but this did not solve the problem it still evaluates to 0.

Comment: @NoCodeNoBlunder you also need brackets, I've edited my answer to show that

Comment: Very bad idea.  Though it can work, linking in `float` for this is overkill.  Scaled integers would work much better.  Almost never need floats in a program this simple.  Bad advice.

Comment: @TomServo Shouldn't be a problem, seeing as these are all constant expressions

Comment: @Artyer ;  That may be true, but it is lazy thinking; if the OP cannot figure out how to do this with integer arithmetic, how is he going to manage when it is not a constant expression?  It is trivial arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic can be considerably simpler and can be performed without the need for floating point.

Consider that `LED_CYCLE_TIME` is:

```
1 / (2 * F_LEDS)
```

and that you are dividing that by `SECONDS_PER_OF`.  But that is the same as *multiplying* by the *reciprocal* of `SECONDS_PER_OF`, and you already calculated that as `OF_FREQUENCY`.  So now you have:

```
1 / (2 * F_LEDS) * OF_FREQUENCY
```

which is the same as:

```
OF_FREQUENCY / (2 * F_LEDS)
```

So what you end up with in code is:

```
#define OF_FREQUENCY (F_CPU / 256)
#define F_LEDS 5
#define OVERFLOWS_PER_CYCLE (OF_FREQUENCY / (2 * F_LEDS))
```

Or better:

```
#define LED_PRESCALER 256
#define F_LEDS 5
#define OVERFLOWS_PER_CYCLE (F_CPU / (LED_PRESCALER * 2 * F_LEDS))
```

Which given `F_CPU == 16000000` is 6250 and requires *no floating point*.

Comment: You are right with this particular numbers there is no need for floating point. But lets say I wanted a 3 Hz blink for some reason then I would need floating point. I was wondering the same at the beginning but thats how they showed it to us at uni so I sticked to it. Appreciate your input though.

Comment: @NoCodeNoBlunder What makes you think that 3Hz makes any dufference? It doesn't. It results in an OF count of 10416, for either solution. Put in the numbers, try it. At university level you should be able to think for yourself, and in this subject more than basic numeracy should be expected. Clearly you have misunderstood what you think you were taught or shown because your solution did not work.